# sp_Who2 is throwing an error when executed against AAG secondary replica

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I am getting following error while trying to execute sp_Who2 or select * from sys.processes against the master database of AlwaysOn secondary replica.
I am using master database but it is still throwing an error. We have 3 instances and i am able to run sp_Who2 against other 2 instances but it throws an error for only one instance.

SQL server 2019- CU19

Error:
The target database ('XXXXX') is in an availability group and is currently accessible for connections when the application intent is set to read only. For more information about application intent, see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: Did you do what it said and use application intent set to readonly?

Comment: I am not using ApplicationIntent=Readonly in my SSMS connection setting. I am executing sp_Who2 and select * from sys.sysprocesses against the master database so it shouldn't throw this error.

Comment: You should try using it, as the error suggests as a corrective action.

Comment: I did try with applicationIntent= ReadOnly and then I am able to run sp_Who2 against secondary but I should be able to run against master system db on secondary without using ApplicationIntent connection.

Comment: I already knew it would work, I'm trying to lead you to the answer which should make sense, which is that you may _execute_ the procedure in a database but that doesn't mean it doesn't access others, which it quite clearly is.

Comment: The target database ('XXXXX') - is XXXXX = master or a user database?
I was able to run `sp_who2` and `SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses` on a secondary replica of `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU20) (KB5024276)`

Comment: The target database ('XXXXX')  - is a user database.